# 'Failed to load the wizard's script error' while creating a wizard for OpenCV in Code::Blocks in Ubuntu 16.04(VirtualBox)

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, codeblocks

I have installed OpenCV 4.0 through terminal in Ubuntu 16.04(VirtualBox).
But when I try to create a new Project in Code::Blocks IDE and when I choose OpenCV as the wizard ,it immediately says 'Failed to load the wizard's script error'.

Any idea how should I tackle this issue?

Comment: I don't know about that particular error, but OpenCV version 4.0 is still in development (and therefore not necessarily stable), so unless you intend to work on the library itself (but then you probably wouldn't be asking this), you should stick to stable releases, (such as 3.4.1). Usually this happens when people build their own copy of OpenCV and forget (or the tutorial they follow doesn't tell them) to check out a tag after cloning the repo.

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you. I will install the previous version (3.4.1) again and will post the status here. It was of great help. Thanks. :)